# How to add link to Title field when list data is fetched using REST API and rendered through Datatable.js

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-server, datatable

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>  
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>  
</body>

 var call = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')/items?$select=Title,Id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
   $('#example').dataTable({
        "sDom": '<"H"Cfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "bProcessing": true,
         "aaData": data.d.results,
         "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "Title",
                          "mData": "Id" } 
      ]
    });
});
```

Using above SharePoint REST API Code I am able to get all list items `Title` & `id` field in the datatable, however what I am looking for is how to add links to `Title` field which will take URL to `DispForm.aspx?Id=??` page. Basically, trying to create a custom view which will have link to Title field and few other columns displayed in the datatable. I have just started using SharePoint REST API and datatable.js so not sure if it can be achieved. If someone knows or have a different idea please share.

Comment: The following blog post may have some useful information for you.  Your issue is with the jQuery Datatable.  You need to learn about its options.  http://www.markrackley.net/2013/10/17/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net/

Comment: CM Kanode, above link was starting point for me to work with REST and datatables, unfortunately it doesnt have information about question asked.

Comment: Did you click on the link for Datatables, and read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a programmer, but probably you can try something like this:

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" 
id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>  
<th>Id</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>  
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('#example tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function (index, element) {
var tn = $(element).text();
var val = $(this).next('td').text();
$(element).html('<a href="https://xxxxx-xxxxx/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + val + '&typ=1&lang=de">' + tn + '</a>');
});
```

You may be able to run this with a function callback within DataTables or just after the table has been generated.